# Binomial trees in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-trees

[image]I'm trying to draw a specific binomial tree in LaTex, the tree is taken from Hull's book, Options, futures and other derivatives. Ive attached the tree im looking to create, and have attached my laTeX for a trinomial i prepared earlier.

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\tikzset{
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  dot/.style={circle, fill, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+3.5pt,
    /utils/exec=\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<4 \rar\urar\drar\fi},
  /tikz/d/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={above:{#1}}},
  /tikz/d</.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={ left:{#1}}},
  /tikz/d>/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={right:{#1}}},
  arrows={-, /tikz/every to/.append style={
    edge node={pic[pos=.95]{arrow=Stealth}}}},
  column sep={3cm,between origins}, row sep={1.33cm,between origins},
]
             &             &               & |[d>=X_0 u^3]| \\
             &             & |[d=X_0 u^2]| & |[d>=X_0 u^2]| \\
             & |[d=X_0 u]| & |[d=X_0 u  ]| & |[d>=X_0 u  ]| \\
  |[d<=X_0]| & |[d=X_0  ]| & |[d=X_0    ]| & |[d>=X_0    ]| \\
             & |[d=X_0 d]| & |[d=X_0 d  ]| & |[d>=X_0 d  ]| \\
             &             & |[d=X_0 d^2]| & |[d>=X_0 d^2]| \\
             &             &               & |[d>=X_0 d^3]|
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Welcome on this site. There are loads of answers on binomial trees here. Have you taken a look at the search bar ?
Also, pls make your code fully compilable with \begin{document} Preambule, etc

Comment: “have attached my laTeX for a trinomial i prepared earlier” – Did *you* prepare it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the question here is about how to make the labels appear both above and below the nodes. This can be accomplished using the syntax `["label1" above, "label2" below]` for the relevant nodes. You can also use `above left`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3cm, row sep=0mm, arrows={-Stealth}, cells={nodes={fill, circle, minimum size=3.5pt, inner sep=0pt, font=\small}}]
 & & |["S_0u^2" above right, "f_{uu}" below right]|\\
 & |["S_0u" above, "f_u" below]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &\\
|["S_0" above left, "f" below left]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] & & |["S_0ud" above right, "f_{ud}" below right]| \\
 & |["S_0d" above, "f_d" below]|\arrow[ur]\arrow[dr] &\\
 & & |["S_0d^2" above right, "f_{dd}" below right]|\\ 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```